# creating a function such as "createRandomVowels" that returns an array containing random vowels

Tags: javascript

```
let sampleData = createRandomVowels(4)
```

The sampleData should store 4 random vowels. E.g. [‘a’, ‘a’, ‘o’, ‘i’]

**More examples**
Input(s):
n (Number)
Output:
An array of ‘n’ random vowels

How would I go about creating a function such as "createRandomVowels" that returns an array containing **n** random vowels? I need to get a user input (1-4) and based on there selection, print out "number" of the vowels in the array. It sounds simple, but clearly I am not able to do it.

Sorry that I do not have too much code to show.

Comment: Show code what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```js
function createRandomVowels(length) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' ];
  return Array.from({ length }, () => vowels[Math.floor(Math.random() * vowels.length)]);
}

console.log(createRandomVowels(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This

```
function createRandomVowels(n) {
    let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    var newArray = [];
    for (var x = 0 ; x < n; x++) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*vowels.length);
        newArray.push(vowels[index]);
    };
    return newArray;
}
}
```